# Why does my style sheet fail to load in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

```
<div class="build-editor" id="section-content">
<link href="/stylesheets/upload-from-disk.css?1280508898" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="attachments">
    <h1 class="at-header">Attachments</h1>
    <div class="at-options">
    .
    .
    .
```

In ie8 and 7, this stylesheet is never loaded... why?

Comment: Where is this at?  Any reason it's not in the `<head>`?

Comment: I like that fact that IE is not a real browser ;)

Comment: Nice jab at IE. of course, it'd sound better if you actually knew how  HTML works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link` should only appear in the `head` of the document.

Comment: i have other pages where link occurs in the body =\

Comment: it should, but it can also appear outside the head depending on the DOCTYPE and the mode the browser is in. IE is infamous for its "quirks" mode.

Comment: This is a good call. however, I was trying to optimize my RoR app, by having stylesheets only load when needed. but i suppose if they are cached, like good browsers do, it won't matter.

Comment: "I was trying to optimize my RoR app, by having stylesheets only load when needed." Well the proper way to go about this IMO would be to make a helper that you can call from your views that adds `link` or `style` tags to the head of what will be the rendered page does RoR not have something like this built in? Both Symfony and Zend do which are what i normally code with.

Comment: Well, my app has a lot of AJAX.. the goal is to not have the page refresh if workflow says its better to stay where we are, and just page-replace.

Answer (score 3):

Try closing the `<link>` element like so...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

I work with several projects that link in CSS from outside the `<head>` area, and I believe it generally works (perhaps not in IE6).

**NOTE**  Even if it works, it is not on-spec.  It's a better idea to place it in the `<head>` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

is your `<link>` placed between `<head></head>` tags?

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to optimize the RoR app.  You can use a content_for..

for example... in your layout...

```
<head>
   <%= yield :head %>
 </head>
```

And

```
<% content_for :head do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'upload-from-disk' %> 
<% end %>
```

in the view..